# Running Ruby script in background for indefinite time

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, backgroundworker

I have a Ruby script that runs/query a database and enters/deletes information every 30 seconds. I run it from command line using:

```
ruby worker.rb
```

I am sshing into the server. When I close the terminal the worker stops running. Is there a way to ensure it keeps running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a Ruby program a daemon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688550/make-a-ruby-program-a-daemon)

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The simple way is to use `nohup` and `&`:

```
nohup ruby worker.rb &
```

Will start it, return control to the shell, and let it run on its own independent of the terminal. Another option is to make it a daemon. This code goes after setup code:

```
Process.daemon
```

Comment: Also it will create nohup.out file where you can log your script results.

Answer (score 2):

For best control you would like to use [**Screen**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [**Tmux**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)

You will be able to start the script as usual(without daemon-ing) and see the output.

You'll can close your SSH session and script(s) will continue running.

Next time you login, you get same environment, just like you never logged out.