# Turn a ruby script into an always running job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman

I have created a program that I need to run constantly. It currently lives at scripts/mailman. I start it by doing this:

```
sudo bundle exec rails runner script/mailman &
```

It seams to stop after I logout of the server. Here is the contents of my mailman program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"
require "rb-inotify"

Mailman.config.logger = Logger.new("/var/log/mailman.log")
Mailman.config.maildir = '/var/mail'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/application"
Rails.application.require_environment!
Mailman::Application.run do
   default do
       begin
           Bin.receive_mail(message)
       end
   end
end
```

What is a good way to start this program automatically and keep it running always? I am running this on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you find a solid answer? We also have issues keeping our mailman server running and I'm considering tying it into Resque.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the `daemons` gem works well for this.

Assuming your posted code lives in `script/mailman.rb`, you can make a file `script/mailman_ctl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'
Daemons.run('mailman.rb')
```

I typically give the options `{:backtrace => true, :monitor => true}` to the `Daemons.run` call, so that I have a better idea of what happened if the process ever dies.

Comment: Ok. I've done that and did:
`sudo ruby script/mailman_ctl start`
but I do not see it running using ps or the log file isn't populating itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'daemons' gem as suggested here:
[Make a Ruby program a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688550/make-a-ruby-program-a-daemon)

Seems also to be very popular on RubyToolbox
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/daemonizing